# More than one if-else in single line, how to interpret them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Well I certainly Understand if-else that are return in single line like

```
return 0 if x==y else 1
```

Which translate to

```
if x==y:
    return 0
else:
    return 1
```

I am confused about those statements where if-else occurs multiple time in one line like

```
def cmp(x, y):
    return 0 if x == y else 1 if x > y else -1
```

How to interpret and understand if-else statements, that are written in single line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Introducing parentheses makes it easier to understand.

```
0 if x == y else 1 if x > y else -1
```

must be parsed as

```
0 if x == y else (1 if x > y else -1)
```

Comment: This is a great answer because it illustrates how things work for even more complicated expressions like `A if cond1 else (B if cond2 else (C if cond3 else (D)))`, though you should generally avoid things like that when possible.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune `though you should generally avoid things like that when possible` True but when i go through most of the python libraries , they are filled with these kind of statements.

Comment: @Rakesh_K Yes, that is true. If you have long chains of single-line if-else statements like that, it's usually a better idea to increase readability by making everything clearer. According to the Zen of Python (`import this`): "Sparse is better than dense," and "If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea." When you start making things like this longer, it becomes more complex, and that means you might consider changing it because "Simple is better than complex," and "Readability counts." Sometimes there are good reasons for complexity, so the Zen doesn't prohibit it.

Answer (score 3):

it's nested else-if ,for clarity it can be seen as this

```
 if x == y:
     return 0
 else:
     if x > y: 
        return 1 
     else: 
        return -1
```

and it would be great if the code is clear and understandable in less possible efforts

So later, what if you want to add one more case in lengthy conditional statements then it can be issue so better option is to use `elif` ladder like this

```
def _comp(total):
    if total>90:
        return 'Python lover'
    elif total>80 and total<=89:
        return 'Friend of python'
  #     elif total>50 and total<=79      added later easily
  #         return 'you like python'     added later easily
    else:
        return 'python is waiting for you'
```